# ReferenceError: logger is not defined (Google Sheets / App Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Why this error?

> ReferenceError: logger is not defined (line 4)

```
function myFunction() {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/destaques");
  var content = res.getContentText();
  logger.log(res);
  logger.log(content);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Logger.log` instead.

**Logger** is the name of the class and `log` is a method of this class.
There is not a built-in class in google scripts called **logger**.

You can also use `console.log` if you have V8 enabled.

See details [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) .

Comment: ```console.log``` perfect solution, thanks mate! I'm waiting 5 minutes to mark your answer to solution for my problem!